# Creating DOK matrix in scipy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have numpy arrays I need to convert to DOK format. Why does this work:

```
x = np.asarray([1, 0, 0])
y = scipy.sparse.dok_matrix(scipy.sparse.csr_matrix(x))
```

But this doesn't:

```
x = np.asarray([1, 0, 0])
y = scipy.sparse.dok_matrix(x)
```

which throws the error:
"TypeError: Expected rank <=2 dense array or matrix."

I don't find anything in Scipy's docs that suggest I shouldn't be able to convert an array to a dok matrix directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`csr_matrix` accepts a 1-d array because it (eventually) passes the array argument through [`numpy.atleast_2d`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.atleast_2d.html).  `dok_matrix` doesn't do that--it *requires* a 2-d array. (I don't know why the behavior is different.)

To work around this, convert your 1-d input to 2-d before passing it to `dok_matrix`.  E.g.

```
y = scipy.sparse.dok_matrix(np.atleast_2d(x))
```

Comment: `dok_matrix` code has explicitly coded this rank test.  Once past that it does the expected `coo_matrix(arg1, dtype=dtype).todok()`.  `coo_matrix` has the `np.atleast_2d` step.